# MVC 5 Global User Account Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a application with the following Layout. In the Shared Views Folder I have, `_Layout.cshtml`, `_SideNav.cshtml` and `_CurrentUser.cshtml`.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` I have:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartialIf("_SideNav", Request.IsAuthenticated); }
```

In the `_SideNav.cshtml` I have:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_CurrentUser"); }
```

In the `_CurrentUser.cshtml` I have:

```
<div class="login-info">
    <span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show-shortcut" data-action="toggleShortcut">
            <img src="~/content/img/avatars/sunny.png" alt="me" class="online" />
            <span>@User.Identity.Name</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

We use `FormsAuthentication` to authenticate a user. We are not using the standard `Identity` authentication which ships with `ASP.Net MVC 5` because we are using a `LDAP` Server.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, isPersistent);
.....
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles);
```

We use the `username` in the cookie so that we can easily get information from the `LDAP` server.

Problem: `@User.Identity.Name` returns that username. But I need to display the full name of the user. I have access to the full name when we authenticate. but not sure how to use it.

How can I pass the `FullName` value from the `AccountController` to the `_CurrentUser.cshtml` partial view? Kind of like a Global Container like `@User.Identity` with more attributes that can be set.

Comment: Are you storing custom data in your authentication cookie?

Comment: Nope just using it out of the box as per above. I have tried a solution to store custom data but that did not work, it would not let me authenticate at all. If you have a solution for me to try I will give it a go.

Comment: The FormsAuthenticationTicket contains a UserData property. This is free to use. After you decrypt the Ticket you can access it with custom object read and write. The custom object can contain additional info you need while the ticket is valid.

Comment: I tried a solution found online and could not authenticate at all for some reason. Also userdata is a string type object so not ideal as later on there needs to be even more additional information stored in there, e.g. organisationname etc

Comment: If your _CurrentUser.cshtml is in one of the pages rendered by the AccountController, Then, you should be able to use the controller to do the heavy lifting (get user info from your db context). Next, you add it to a viewbag variable and consume it in your _CurrentUser view as @ViewBag.myvar, (as well as through language code on the view if you prefer)

Comment: @nocturns2 Unfortunately no controller renders any of the shared partial views. Its all based on if a request if authenticated or not. Thank you for your reply though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                                                viewModel.Email,
                                                                YOUR_ISSUE_DATE,
                                                                YOUR_EXPIRE_DATE,
                                                                viewModel.RememberMe,
                                                                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user),
                                                                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);


string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie authcookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

Response.Cookies.Add(authcookie);
```

Comment: How would you abstract that user data in the view tho?

Comment: When the user logs in, and you have the FullName, create a user object containing everything you want. Then serialize that into the cookie.  To display the details in the `_CurrentUser.cshtml` have that view use the User object as viewModel, and then render the screen passing it the `User` object

Comment: Thank you I managed to get this one to work. In my `.cshtml` file i added a code block to grab the data. I'm sure there is a better way but it will work for now. I tried a similar solution before but for some reason it did not work at all, no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to-->

```
public static MyAuthenticationTicket  GetIMyUserTicket()
{
    //Get custom user data object from forms auth cookie
    MyAuthenticationTicket  result= null;
    if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
        return null;
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        return null;
    FormsIdentity ident = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    if (ident == null)
        return null;
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ident.Ticket;
    if (ticket == null)
        return null;
    if (!FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
    {               
        //If cookie is not supported for forms authentication, then the 
        //authentication ticket is stored in the Url, which is encrypted.
        //So, decrypt it
        ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(ident.Ticket.Name);

    }

    string userDataString = ticket.UserData;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userDataString))
        result= new MyAuthenticationTicket(userDataString);

    return result;       
}
```

Comment: I am confused as to where this needs to go / fits in. I have tried this, and does not work. http://pastebin.com/ers0ipQ5

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClaimsIdentity`.

When the user login to your app add his name to your identity.

```
ClaimsIdentity claims = new ClaimsIdentity();
claims.AddClaim(new Claim("name", "value"));
```

Then create a extension method to get your name

```
 public static string GetName(this IPrincipal principal)
 {
     return ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "name").FirstOrDefault().Value;
 }
```

Now use it as `@User.GetName()`

Update:

Or in you login controller use `UserManager` to get the user identity.
Like this:

```
ClaimsIdentity claims = UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
claims.Add(new Claim("name" , "value"));

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(claims);
```

Comment: Where do you add the claims to?

Comment: Add claims in your login controller

Comment: This is for ASP.NET Identity. This does not work with FormsAuthentication.